# hover on corner of rounded corners button

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, rounded-corners

I would like to capture the hover event on a corner of element with rounded corners, using jquery.
currently the hover is active when the cursor is actually on the shape and not on the rectangle of the shape as I marked in the image below:

[image]

please help!

Comment: You want to capture only on hover of corner or full rectangular?

Comment: full rectangular, currently jquery captures only the shape - without corners

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make one more button with sizes of this rounded button but make it without rounded corners. Then place it above rounded, make it transparent and catch hover of this button

Comment: that would work but this solution is impossible, I can touch the markup, need to find a solution with only JS or CSS

Comment: Can you post css and JS of button? I'll try to find solution via CSS-after